# MPI several broadcast at the same time

Tags: mpi, broadcast

I have a 2D processor grid (3*3):

P00, P01, P02 are in R0, P10, P11, P12, are in R1, P20, P21, P22 are in R2.
P*0 are in the same computer. So the same to P*1 and P*2.

Now I would like to let R0, R1, R2 call MPI_Bcast at the same time to broadcast from P*0 to p*1 and P*2.

I find that when I use MPI_Bcast, it takes three times the time I need to broadcast in only one row.

For example, if I only call MPI_Bcast in R0, it takes 1.00 s.
But if I call three MPI_Bcast in all R[0, 1, 2], it takes 3.00 s in total.
It means the MPI_Bcast cannot work parallel.

Is there any methods to make the MPI_Bcast broadcast at the same time?
(ONE node broadcast with three channels at the same time.)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your code? It'll be easier to help if we can see how you are calling `MPI_Bcast()`. Also post any *communicator* set-up, if that's what you're using for the groupings.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question right, you would like to have simultaneous row-wise broadcasts:

```
P00 -> P01 & P02
P10 -> P11 & P12
P20 -> P21 & P22
```

This could be done using subcommunicators, e.g. one that only has processes from row 0 in it, another one that only has processes from row 1 in it and so on. Then you can issue simultaneous broadcasts in each subcommunicator by calling `MPI_Bcast` with the appropriate communicator argument.

Creating row-wise subcommunicators is extreamly easy if you use Cartesian communicator in first place. MPI provides the `MPI_CART_SUB` operation for that. It works like that:

```c
// Create a 3x3 non-periodic Cartesian communicator from MPI_COMM_WORLD
int dims[2] = { 3, 3 };
int periods[2] = { 0, 0 };
MPI_Comm comm_cart;

// We do not want MPI to reorder our processes
// That's why we set reorder = 0
MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 2, dims, periods, 0, &comm_cart);

// Split the Cartesian communicator row-wise
int remaindims[2] = { 0, 1 };
MPI_Comm comm_row;

MPI_Cart_sub(comm_cart, remaindims, &comm_row);
```

Now `comm_row` will contain handle to a new subcommunicator that will only span the same row that the calling process is in. It only takes a single call to `MPI_Bcast` now to perform three simultaneous row-wise broadcasts:

```c
MPI_Bcast(&data, data_count, MPI_DATATYPE, 0, comm_row);
```

This works because `comm_row` as returned by `MPI_Cart_sub` will be different in processes located at different rows. `0` here is the rank of the first process in `comm_row` subcommunicator which will correspond to `P*0` because of the way the topology was constructed.

If you do not use Cartesian communicator but operate on `MPI_COMM_WORLD` instead, you can use `MPI_COMM_SPLIT` to split the world communicator into three row-wise subcommunicators. `MPI_COMM_SPLIT` takes a `color` that is used to group processes into new subcommunicators - processes with the same `color` end up in the same subcommunicator. In your case `color` should equal to the number of the row that the calling process is in. The splitting operation also takes a `key` that is used to order processes in the new subcommunicator. It should equal the number of the column that the calling process is in, e.g.:

```c
// Compute grid coordinates based on the rank
int proc_row = rank / 3;
int proc_col = rank % 3;
MPI_Comm comm_row;

MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, proc_row, proc_col, &comm_row);
```

Once again `comm_row` will contain the handle of a subcommunicator that only spans the same row as the calling process.

Answer (score 1):

The MPI-3.0 draft includes a non-blocking `MPI_Ibcast` collective.  While the non-blocking collectives aren't officially part of the standard yet, they are already available in MPICH2 and (I think) in OpenMPI.

Alternatively, you could start the blocking `MPI_Bcast` calls from separate threads (I'm assuming R0, R1 and R2 are different communicators).

A third possibility (which may or may not be possible) is to restructure the data so that only one broadcast is needed.